# mxnet cpu memory leak when running inference on GPT2 model

Tags: memory

I am testing GPT2.
This code takes a question and predicts the next word.

```py
def chat(model, vocab, sentence):
    q = sentence
    if q == 'quit':
        return
    q_tok = tok(q)
    a = ''
    a_tok = []

    break_check_idx=0
    prev_gen = ''

    while 1:
        input_ids = mx.nd.array([vocab[U_TKN]] + vocab[q_tok] +
                                    vocab[EOS, SENT] + 
                                    vocab[EOS, S_TKN] +
                                    vocab[a_tok]).expand_dims(axis=0) # <--- Here

        pred = model(input_ids.as_in_context(ctx)) # <--- Here
            
        gen = vocab.to_tokens(
            mx.nd.argmax(
                pred,
                axis=-1).squeeze().astype('int').asnumpy().tolist())[-1] # <--- Here
        if gen == EOS:
            break
        if prev_gen == gen:
            break_check_idx += 1
            if break_check_idx == 5:
                break_check_idx = 0
                prev_gen = ''
                return '๑°⌓°๑ ...?'
        prev_gen = gen
        a += gen.replace('▁', ' ')
        a_tok = tok(a)
    return a.strip()
```

As a result of tracking memory using several tools, memory is allocated from the indicated area.

No matter how much I search, I do not know the cause. Where is the memory leaking?

I tried del, mx.nd.waitall(), gc.collect(), ctx.empty_cache(), jemalloc all.